# How to keep a flexbox from expanding horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been all over the net, tried many solutions, none of which work.  I have a container that will house several rows (like a data grid).  The row is defined in the following manner:

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid 
}
.row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  display: flex;  
  align-items:center;
}
.row-left{
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;  
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.row-middle{
  flex:1 0 0;  
  background-color: green;
}
.row-right{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.subject{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">X</div>
    <div class="row-middle">
      <div class="subject">
      This is what I am supposed to look like.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-right">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">X</div>
    <div class="row-middle">
      <div class="subject">
      This is what I look like when my text is too long.  How can we possibly fix this to hide the overflow and ellipses the text?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-right">X</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I need to keep `row-middle` a static size and handle the text overflow with ellipses.

Comment: Removing `whitespcace: nowrap`  fixes the issue of the flexbox expanding; however the content now wraps instead of breaking off with the ellipses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-webkit-line-clamp` property

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid 
}
.row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  display: flex;  
  align-items:center;
}
.row-left{
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;  
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.row-middle{
  flex:1 0 0;  
  background-color: green;
}
.row-right{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.subject{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
   display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">X</div>
    <div class="row-middle">
      <div class="subject">
      This is what I am supposed to look like.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-right">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">X</div>
    <div class="row-middle">
      <div class="subject">
      This is what I look like when my text is too long.  How can we possibly fix this to hide the overflow and ellipses the text?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-right">X</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

You can read more about it over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)

Also, please do check browser [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_-webkit-line-clamp)

Comment: It would be good to include the actual spec-compliant property and not just the vendor-prefixed version.

Answer (score 0):

A flex item's minimum width defaults to the width of its content. Since the text is inside an element, this explains why the long text is blowing out the layout.

A way to adjust for this problem is to give the flex item a `min-width: 0` style.

```css
.row-middle{
  …
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid 
}
.row{
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  display: flex;  
  align-items:center;
}
.row-left{
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;  
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.row-middle{
  flex:1 0 0;  
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 0;
}
.row-right{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.subject{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">X</div>
    <div class="row-middle">
      <div class="subject">
      This is what I am supposed to look like.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-right">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-left">X</div>
    <div class="row-middle">
      <div class="subject">
      This is what I look like when my text is too long.  How can we possibly fix this to hide the overflow and ellipses the text?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-right">X</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that.  Didn't work.

Comment: Wondering what you tried then, since the code snippet appears to work fine.